# Best way for changeable Qt canvas

Tags: c++, qt

What is the most effective way of creating "canvas" with high change frequency in Qt?

Currently I have a main application window (QWidget) where I create a QPixmap and set it to a QLabel:

```
QPixmap *canvas = new QPixmap(500, 500);
QLabel *area = new QLabel(this);
area->setPixmap(canvas);
```

The problem is that I have to call `area->setPixmap(canvas);` after every change I make on the pixmap so that it can be displayed (I'm counting there will be normally several changes every second). Is this way ok? Or is there a better/faster/more efficient solution?

Comment: What are you drawing on the canvas?

Comment: @peppe Mostly text.

Comment: a QGraphicsScene with a few QGraphicsItems might make more sense, especially if they're incremental changes and not everything is changed on each update.

Comment: How about subclassing QWidget and overriding paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) to draw whatever you need to draw using a QPainter(this) ?   (Just call update() whenever you need to show a new version, and paintEvent() will be called again ASAP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PeterT and Jeremy both have good solutions. Which one is best depends on your needs.

If you are moving items around and changing them, use a `QGraphicsScene` to store the data you want to display and readily manipulate it. Use a `QGraphicsView` to display the result.

If you are already doing the rendering elsewhere as a `QPixmap` and just want to draw the result, subclassing `QWidget` and drawing it in the `paintEvent` using `QPainter` may be simpler. Remember to call `update()`, though!